# PHP-Maven :: The desired archetype does not exist

Tags: php, maven, maven-3

I'm trying to install php-maven from the following instructions:

http://www.php-maven.org/tags/2.0.0/php-web-5min.html

and yes, I did the preparation instructions.

I have all the prerequisites installed (maven 3, php > 5.2, phpdocumentor, pear in path)

Should I do some changes to the settings.xml?
I just copy pasted the settings.xml into ~/.m2 folder, but to no avail.

While running this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.phpmaven \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=php5-web-archetype \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.0.0 \
-DgroupId=org.sample \
-DartifactId=my-app \
-Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2).
[WARNING] Use -DarchetypeRepository=<your repository> if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/phpmaven/php5-zend-archetype/2.0.0/php5-zend-archetype-2.0.0.jar
Downloading: http://repos.php-maven.org/releases/org/phpmaven/php5-zend-archetype/2.0.0/php5-zend-archetype-2.0.0.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/phpmaven/php5-zend-archetype/2.0.0/php5-zend-archetype-2.0.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.238s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 27 06:31:42 UTC 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/36M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org
.phpmaven:php5-zend-archetype:2.0.0) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: tried adding `-DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.php-maven.org/content/repositories/php-maven-plugin-snapshots`. Same error